# Using two select in one query

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have two SQL queries for counting the rows from the table `tContentNode`, depending on the type 2 or 3.
**Query 1:**

```
SELECT count(*) _countA FROM TCONTENTNODE WHERE type = '2' 
     AND parentid ='02b3abc2-4983-485a-ab09-1a8cb328b9b5';
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT count(*) _countB FROM TCONTENTNODE WHERE type = '3' 
     AND parentid ='02b3abc2-4983-485a-ab09-1a8cb328b9b5';
```

Now I want to get the values of `_countA` and `_countB` using only one query. How can I get the counts using one query. Is there any way to do that. I am using SQLite Database.

**EDIT:**
I want values of `_countA` and `_countB` separately, not both together(Not using `IN`).

Comment: `GROUPY BY type` gives you two rows. So you do want to have two columns instead?

Comment: @CL. I want those values in the variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `group by`

```
SELECT type,count(*) as cnt
FROM TCONTENTNODE 
WHERE parentid ='02b3abc2-4983-485a-ab09-1a8cb328b9b5';
group by type
```

for two variables:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(case TCONTENTNODE.type when '2' then 1 end) as _countA,
  COUNT(case TCONTENTNODE.type when '3' then 1 end) as _countB
FROM  TCONTENTNODE 
WHERE TCONTENTNODE.parentid ='02b3abc2-4983-485a-ab09-1a8cb328b9b5';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will give me the count when the value is either `2` or `3`. But I want in two different variables, one count for type `2` and one count for type `3` and not the total count.

Comment: No error, but it gives me both countA and countB as 4 instead of 3 and 1

Comment: Show us what do you expect in result.

Comment: I removed in condition from 1st query.

Comment: Thanks, parado your answer helped me. But thats not what I wanted. The query given in my answer worked.

Comment: Is this  the same question as my 2nd solution?

Comment: In your second solution you are counting even if the type is not 2 or 3 in the else part. I removed the else part from that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17118/discussion-between-jai-and-parado)

Comment: `else 0` doesn't increase result.

Comment: It does. I am getting both counts as equal to each other

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem using the following query:-

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(case TCONTENTNODE.type when '2' then 1  end) as _countA,
  COUNT(case TCONTENTNODE.type when '3' then 1  end) as _countB
FROM  TCONTENTNODE 
WHERE TCONTENTNODE.parentid ="02b3abc2-4983-485a-ab09-1a8cb328b9b5";
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont have SQLite to confirm but

```
select count(*), type FROM TCONTENTNODE WHERE (type = '2' or type = '3' )
     AND parentid ='02b3abc2-4983-485a-ab09-1a8cb328b9b5' group by type
```

Just to clarify this will return

```
count type

23     2
23888  3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will give me the count when the value is either `2` or `3`. But I want in two different variables, one count for type `2` and one count for type `3` and not the total count.

Comment: thats what I am asking. I want 2 counts, 1 for 2, and 1 for 3.

Comment: btw the group by will mean that there is a line for each type you selected

Comment: This answer is correct. The query will provide the count for the two types separately.

Answer (score 0):

Use IN KeyWord

> SELECT count(*) _countB FROM TCONTENTNODE WHERE (type IN (3,2) AND
>   parentid ='02b3abc2-4983-485a-ab09-1a8cb328b9b5');