# How can I reuse the results of a WITH clause for two queries in Redshift / Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-redshift

(Asking about Redshift's subset of PostgreSQL)

This is an *"I want a pony"* question: I know how to do this using explicit temporary tables, but would prefer to avoid that.

I would like to run two completely different selects in one query (i.e. generate two tables in one ;-terminated query). *To be explicit, I would like to (ab)use the WITH syntax to make use of the temporary tables generated internally by Redshift.* To whit:

```
with TempTable as ( some query ),
AnotherTempTable as ( some other query ),
YetAnotherTable as ( some query based on TempTable and AnotherTempTable )
select something-joined-with-The-tables-above, (comma?)
...
select something-else-joined-with-The-tables-above;
```

Being able to "output" the results of the WITH clauses would not only be fine, but ideal. I.e. a yet undiscovered modifier to select:

```
with Stuff as (select blah from ... force_output) ...
```

And once again, I want two different tables put out, not just one humongously-wide OUTER JOIN with lots of empty space.

***The point behind this is to rely on as much Redshift internals as possible.*** The theory is that the less you explicitly state, the more Redshift can optimize internally. This SHOULD provide for a faster and less resource-intensive query, as well as make use of any "new" optimizations that might be silently dropped in by Amazon.

This is ESPECIALLY important on very large datasets, which Redshift is meant for.

[Please note that this is NOT a duplicate of this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579772/using-two-select-in-one-query) This is about reusing the results of with clauses (i.e. embedded selects)

Comment: That's not possible. A common table expression is only valid in a single statement. If you want to re-use that for multiple statements, create a view.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was afraid of. I was hopeful that there was some kind of Redshift and/or secret Postgres modifier, but so be it.

As such, can you please state this in the form of an answer (says Alex Trebec), so that I can select it? Thanks!